# Convert simple JAVA code to PHP (arrays)

Tags: java, php, arrays

I am not familiar with PHP, and it is hard for me to understand arrays in PHP.
I have some problem to resolve, and I write simple JAVA class to resolve it, but I need it in PHP. Could some one help me to covert this below code to PHP?

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> outputData = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
        int[][] inputData = new int[6][2];
        inputData[0][0] = 1;
        inputData[0][1] = 22;
        inputData[1][0] = 1;
        inputData[1][1] = 33;
        inputData[2][0] = 2;
        inputData[2][1] = 44;
        inputData[3][0] = 2;
        inputData[3][1] = 55;
        inputData[4][0] = 3;
        inputData[4][1] = 66;
        inputData[5][0] = 1;
        inputData[5][1] = 77;

        // process input data
        for(int i = 0;i<=5;i++){
            if(outputData.containsKey(inputData[i][0])){
                List<Integer> list = outputData.get(inputData[i][0]);
                list.add(inputData[i][1]);

            }else{
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                list.add(inputData[i][1]);
                outputData.put(inputData[i][0], list);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("INPUT DATA DISPLAY");
        for(int i = 0;i<=5;i++){
            System.out.println("i: "+inputData[i][0] + " = "+inputData[i][1]);
        }
        System.out.println("OUTPUT MAP");
        for(Integer i : outputData.keySet()){
            List<Integer> l = outputData.get(i);
            System.out.print("i: "+i+" = ");
            for(Integer j : l){
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

I have input table:

```
i: 1 = 22
i: 1 = 33
i: 2 = 44
i: 2 = 55
i: 3 = 66
i: 1 = 77
```

and I need it to group elements by key. 
This is output:

```
i: 1 = 22 33 77 
i: 2 = 44 55 
i: 3 = 66
```

In JAVA it is working as expected, but in PHP I am not able to write it, though I read some tutorials, manuals and examples.

[EDIT]:
The real issue is:
I have an excel file with N rows (loading excel is implemented).
Every row have 2 columns.

[image]

I want to group it like this:

- data from column B should be grouped by value from column A.

In this case:

- for value 1 it will be 123, 63, 3 (rows 1, 2 and 6)
- for value 2 it will be 3, 23 (rows 3 and 4)
- for value 3 it will be 55, 234 (rows 5 and 7)

Comment: Hard to say if it is an duplicate. I know that automatically convert is not possible. I need help to write in PHP above logic implemented in JAVA,

Comment: Probably you're right, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the input data must be changed, because in PHP the keys must be unique. I have tested this code: (it is much simpler than in JAVA)
(So the input is an array of associative arrays.)

```
<?php

function groupByKey($input) {
    $result = array();

    foreach($input as $item) {
        foreach($item as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key][] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$data = array(
    array(1 => 22),
    array(1 => 33),
    array(2 => 44),
    array(2 => 55),
    array(3 => 66),
    array(1 => 77)
);

print_r($data);
echo "\n\n";

$result = groupByKey($data);

print_r($result);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 33
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => 44
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => 55
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [3] => 66
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => 77
        )

)


Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 33
            [2] => 77
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44
            [1] => 55
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 66
        )

)
```

Comment: In fact, in JAVA I parsed xls in format: 'row1, row2,..,rowN'. Every row has  columns: col1, col2. Colums are not unique. I will look into your code. Thanks.